How to destroy the flutter web build being used in react on parent component unmount?
I have implemented a bridge between flutter web build and react app to show the flutter app inside a react component. I am able to render the app and update its state from react's end. The problem I am facing is that when I unmount the wrapper react component, the flutter app residing inside it is not being destroyed (I still see logs after closing the parent component).
This is how I have done it:

I made edits to /web/index.html file, added this script tag:

 <script>
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
       window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
         navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js?v=1417913520');
         navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
       });
     }
     window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
       // Download main.dart.js
       entrypointUrl: "/main.dart.js",
       _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
         serviceWorker: {
           serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
         },
         onEntrypointLoaded: function (engineInitializer) {
           engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function (appRunner) {
             appRunner.runApp();
           });
         }
       });
     });
   </script>

and added this to head:
<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

Added this script to package.json, this basically builds the flutter app and keeps the build folder in public folder of my react app:
"prebuild-estimations-ff": "cd <flutterapp> && flutter clean && flutter build web --base-href $PUBLIC_URL/ --output=../public/flutter && cd -"

Created this react component that renders the flutter app and also updated its states:


// The global _flutter namespace
declare let _flutter: any;

export const FlutterEmbedComponent: React.FC<> = memo(({
  assetBase = '',
  src = 'main.dart.js',
}) => {
  const flutterState = useRef<any>(null);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const onFlutterAppLoaded = (state: any) => {
    flutterState.current = state;

    // Update Flutter state once when loaded
    state.stateone(stateone);
    state.statetwo(statetwo);
   // and so on...
    
    state.updateEnv(ENV);
    state.listenToFlutterState(state => {
      console.log(">>> state from flutter: ", state);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const target = ref.current;
    let engineInitializer;
    let appRunner;
  
    const initFlutterApp = async () => {
      engineInitializer = await new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
        _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
          entrypointUrl: src,
          onEntrypointLoaded: resolve,
        });
      });
  
      console.log('initialize Flutter engine...');
      appRunner = await engineInitializer?.initializeEngine({
        hostElement: target,
        assetBase: assetBase,
      });
  
      console.log('run Flutter engine...');
      await appRunner?.runApp();
      // Save the appRunner for later cleanup
      flutterState.current = appRunner;
    };
  
    initFlutterApp();
  
    const eventListener = (event: Event) => {
      let state = (event as CustomEvent).detail;
      console.log('Flutter app initialized:', state);
      onFlutterAppLoaded(state);
    };
  
    target?.addEventListener('flutter-initialized', eventListener, { once: true });
  
    return () => {
      // Remove the event listener
      target?.removeEventListener('flutter-initialized', eventListener);
  
      // Cleanup Flutter app by removing the host element and resetting state
      if (flutterState.current) {
        console.log('Cleaning up Flutter app...');
        if (target && target.parentNode) {
          target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
        }
        flutterState.current = null;
      }
  
      // Ensure other state cleanup if necessary
      if (engineInitializer) {
        engineInitializer = null;
      }
      if (appRunner) {
        appRunner = null;
      }
    };
  }, [assetBase, src]);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    flutterState.current?.stateone(stateone);
  }, [stateone]);

  useEffect(() => {
    flutterState.current?.statetwo(statetwo);
  }, [statetwo]);

  // and so on

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      style={{
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        display: showFlutterApp ? 'flex' : 'none',
        zIndex: 99,
        position: activePage === 2 ? 'fixed' : 'static',
        top: activePage === 2 ? 50 : 'auto',
        right: activePage === 2 ? 0 : 'auto',
        flex: 1
      }}
    ></div>
  );
});

I still see logs (>>> state from flutter:, and also some logs written on flutter side) when I unmount this component. How can I dispose this flutter app when react component is unmounted?

I think you need to properly dispose your flutter app when the React component unmounts,
You need to explicitly clean up engine initializer. Consider using ref for that.
using useRef will ensure that engineInitializer and appRunner can persist and be cleaned up properly.
Add the following refs in your FlutterEmbedComponent :
const engineInitializerRef = useRef<any>(null);
const appRunnerRef = useRef<any>(null);

and in the useEffect function, consider storing & cleaning these refs,
useEffect(() => {
const target = ref.current;
let engineInitializer;
let appRunner;

const initFlutterApp = async () => {
   // function as it is   

  // Save the appRunner and engineInitializer for later cleanup
  engineInitializerRef.current = engineInitializer;
  appRunnerRef.current = appRunner;
};

initFlutterApp();

const eventListener = (event: Event) => {
  const state = (event as CustomEvent).detail;
  console.log('Flutter app initialized:', state);
  onFlutterAppLoaded(state);
};

target?.addEventListener('flutter-initialized', eventListener, { once: true });

return () => {
  // Remove the event listener
  target?.removeEventListener('flutter-initialized', eventListener);

  // Cleanup Flutter app by stopping the app and removing the host element
  if (appRunnerRef.current) {
    console.log('Stopping Flutter app...');
    appRunnerRef.current = null;
  }

  if (engineInitializerRef.current) {
    console.log('Cleaning up Flutter engine...');
    engineInitializerRef.current = null;
  }

  // Ensure the target element is removed from the DOM
  if (target && target.parentNode) {
    target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
  }

  flutterState.current = null;
};
  }, [assetBase, src]);

Please let me know if this resolves the issue.
